# Xcode 13b3 : No preview available (no bundle)

Tags: xcode, xcode13

Just downloaded the latest Xcode 13 beta 3 but i can't get the preview working:

> PlatformDoesNotHaveAgentsError: Missing required components for iOS
>
> Xcode is missing components needed to preview on iOS
>
> ==================================
>
> |  HumanReadableSwiftError |   |  LocationError: noBundle

Rebooting not helped.

Tested on MBP Intel, macOS 11.4

I don't know if it's a problem on my mac or a bug introduced in this version.

Any clue ?

Edit: It look like to only works when you select an iOS 15 simulator, you can not longer uses iOS 14.x version...

Comment: Confirmed it works on iOS 15 simulator, not 14.x. Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

What fixed it for me was selecting a simulator that had the iOS version on it that the version of xcode was built for.. ex: Select simulator with iOS 15 when using XCode Beta 13

Comment: I confirm it worked for me too with Xcode 13 beta 5

Comment: Works with Xcode 13.1 Release

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem with Xcode 13.1. Today, Xcode 13.2 was released, and iOS 14.5 now also works with Canvas without this issue in this new version for me. So, this issue seems to be fixed.

PS. Be aware of the problem with the app store version: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696504, https://www.macrumors.com/2021/12/14/xcode-13-2-bug/